# Prove a function attains each complex value.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p$ and $q$ be non constant polynomials. Prove that the function $f(z) =p(z) e^{q(z)} $ attains every complex value.

I tried to use the little picard but i cant solve it. 
I assumed that there exists $w_0$ complex that $f$ does not attain. Then i wrote $p(z) =\frac{f(z)} {e^{q(z)}} $. The problem is that the argument that since $f$ ommits $w_0$ and the denominator ommits the value one does not imply that the polynomial $p$ommits also the same value hence a contradiction. Could you help me?

Comment: What do you know about poles?

Comment: I think you can use all the standard complex function theory. The question is from an old qualifying exam

Comment: Hint: great Picard's theorem.

Comment: My first thought was to use Picard's theorem. Then f ommits at most one value. Then assuming that it ommits some value i tried to constract a non constant function that ommits two values to find a contradiction. I also tried the argument principle but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Tzakrevskiy can you help me a little bit more? Do i have to combine the big with the little picard? I dont have much experience in picard's theorems and i find it difficult to follow the hint